# tensorflow, how to do tf.Print in mnist for ml beginners

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I'm trying the getting started example of tensorflow on this [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners). I'd like to print sth with respect to cross_entropy but got nothing.
Here is the code, it can also be referred from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax_xla.py#L33-L95).

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_))
cross_entropy = tf.Print(cross_entropy, [cross_entropy], "###")
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for _ in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_:  mnist.test.labels}))
```

I cannot find out why `tf.Print`, which is bound to cross_entropy, printing nothing in each loop.

I think I've already bound tf.Print -> cross_entropy -> train_step and run this train_step. What's my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, `tf.Print` is (quoting the documentation):

> an identity op with the side effect of printing data when evaluating.

Therefore, rightly, you expect to see the value of `cross_entropy` everytime something flows across the `cross_entropy` node.

The problem is that you're minimizing the real cross entropy and not the identity node. Thus, in practice, the `cross_entropy` variable is an identity node that "points" to another variable, that is effectively evaluated.

To solve this, you can force the order of evaluation of the nodes in the graph.

You can constrain the minimization step of being executed only after logging the value. To do this you can use `tf.control_dependencies` in this way:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_))

with tf.control_dependencies([tf.Print(cross_entropy, [cross_entropy], "###")]):
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(
    sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                                  y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: So the reason is that the tensorflow evaluation process isn't executed correctly due to the wrong variable binding ?

Comment: I'm not completely sure that the evaluation isn't executed correctly. I suggest you open an issue on GitHub linking this thread: maybe the TF developers can understand and explain to us why without `tf.control_dependencies` the `tf.Print` doesn't work. My guess is that `cross_entropy` becomes a reference node and not a real node, thus nothing flows into the reference, but It's just my understanding of how tensorflow works. Open the issue and then link it here, I'm interested too (maybe it's a bug!).